# Add sequence between each pair of values of a numeric vector

Tags: r, vector, sequence

I have a numeric vector, which I would like to extent with a sequence of three additional numbers between each two values of this vector.

Consider the following example:

```
# Example vector
set.seed(123)
x <- round(runif(5, 0, 100))
x
### 29 79 41  88 94
```

I want to insert 3 new numbers between each of these five values. The numbers should be a sequence of length 3 between each pair of values.

The output should look as follows:

```
# Desired output
c(seq(29, 79, length.out = 5),
  seq(79, 41, length.out = 5)[- 1],
  seq(41, 88, length.out = 5)[- 1],
  seq(88, 94, length.out = 5)[- 1])
# 29 42 54 66 79 70 60 50 41 53 64 76 88 90 91 92 94
```

The added sequence between 29 and 79 is 42, 54, 66; the added sequence between 79 and 41 is 70, 60, 50; and so on...

How could I do such an operation in an automated way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is `Map` to get the sequence of adjacent numbers by removing the `last` element and `first` element, remove the first element from the `list`,  `unlist` the output and append the first element of vector

```
c(x[1], unlist(lapply(Map(seq, x[-length(x)], x[-1],
           MoreArgs = list(length.out = 5)), `[`, -1)))
#[1] 29.00 41.50 54.00 66.50 79.00 69.50 60.00 50.50 41.00 
#[11] 52.75 64.50 76.25 88.00 89.50 91.00 92.50 94.00
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Unfortunately, you code is not exactly providing the desired output, since the original numbers are included twice. Your output is `29 42 54 66 79 79 70 60 50 41 41 53 64 76 88 88 90 91 92 94` instead of `29 42 54 66 79 70 60 50 41 53 64 76 88 90 91 92 94`. Is there a way to modify your code?

Comment: @JSP  You meant to remove the first element, right?

Comment: @JSP Now, check the output

Comment: v nice. `unlist(lapply(...))` could also be `sapply` to me :)

Comment: @tjebo thanks. I generally use `lapply` as `sapply` default option `simplify = TRUE` can sometimes be an issue

Answer (score 2):

A not fancy solution is:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- round(runif(5, 0, 100))
x

c(x[1], unlist(lapply(X = 1:(length(x)-1), function(i) seq(x[i], x[i+1], length.out = 5)[-1])))
[1] 29.00 41.50 54.00 66.50 79.00 69.50 60.00 50.50 41.00 52.75 64.50 76.25 88.00 89.50 91.00 92.50 94.00
```

Actually your seed generates this values: `29 79 41 88 94`

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for the mistake with the seed. Your code is not producing the desired output though, since it adds only one number between each pair of values and then repeats the original values twice. Is there a way to modify your code accordingly?

Comment: You are right. My mistake. I will edit my answer. Actually the parameter `length.out` must be `5`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the alternative solution!